# Magento 2: Rest API update multiple cart Items

Tags: rest-api, magento2.3.4, cart-items

I need to update **multiple cart items** quantity in Rest API.

Default Magento only have update single cart item.

**Single cart update Item endpoint:**

> /V1/carts/mine/items/:itemId

I have tried with custom endpoint but not get update multiple items.

**Multiple item custom endpoint:**

localhost/magento2/rest/V1/custom/carts/mine/update/items?cartItem[0][item_id]=85411&cartItem[0][qty]=2&cartItem[0][quote_id]=25645&cartItem[1][item_id]=85412&cartItem[1][qty]=1&cartItem[1][quote_id]=25645

**Params:**

```
cartItem[0][item_id]   85411
cartItem[0][qty]       2
cartItem[0][quote_id]  25645
cartItem[1][item_id]   85412
cartItem[1][qty]       1
cartItem[1][quote_id]  25645
```

**Method:** PUT

Let me know if any have idea about to update multiple cart items in rest API.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call the items in the loop and load quote object and set quantity or another field.

> sample code

```
 public function updateItems($cartId, $cartItem)
  {
   $result = $this->dataObjectFactory->create();
   $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);        
   foreach ($cartItem as $itemValue) {
     $item = $this->quoteItemFactory->create()->load($itemValue['item_id']);
     $item = $quote->getItemById($itemValue['item_id']);
     $item->setQty($itemValue['qty']);
     $quoteItems[] = $item;
  }     
  $quote->setItems($quoteItems);
  $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
  $quote->collectTotals();
  $quote->getLastAddedItem();}
```

Please let me know if this is helpful.